# how delete data from second table when row in first are deleting

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design, triggers

I have 2 simple tables in SQLite.

1st table :notebook_id, notebook_name

```
(1, lenovo) 
(2, hp)
```

2nd table: model_id, notebook_id, model_name, price

for example

```
(1, 1, y580, 1000)
(2, 1, y510p, 1500)
```

When i delete lenovo from first table i'd like delete lenovo's models from second table too. I know i should use trigger but will be great if somebody explain me triggers on this simple example.

I'm adding code which works fine, i hope it helps somebody.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
       BEFORE DELETE ON notebook
BEGIN
    DELETE
      FROM model
     WHERE notebook_id = old.notebook_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually called a parent-child relationship.
So the 1st table is your parent table, the 2nd table is your child table. 
You can setup cascade delete so that when a parent row is deleted, 
all child rows belonging to that parent row are deleted too.

For more information see:

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

and especially this part:

*"4.3. ON DELETE and ON UPDATE Actions"*

See the example there with artists and tracks, it is 
practically similar to your case (if not identical).

Of course, you can also handle this in your app,
and do it yourself i.e. before deleting the parent row,
just go to the child table and delete all child rows
pointing to that particular parent row.